# Dataframe group columns to nested json

Tags: python, json, pandas

I want to output a dataframe by grouping by the first 2 columns in a dictionary format. This is my dataframe:

```
    COMUNIDAD   PROVINCIA   EMPLAZAMIENTO
0   ANDALUCIA   ALMERIA ALMERIA
1   ANDALUCIA   ALMERIA EJIDO, EL
2   ANDALUCIA   ALMERIA HUERCAL OVERA
3   ANDALUCIA   ALMERIA PECHINA
4   ANDALUCIA   ALMERIA VELEZ BLANCO
... ... ... ...
246 VALENCIA    VALENCIA    COFRENTES
247 VALENCIA    VALENCIA    MONDUBER
248 VALENCIA    VALENCIA    ONTENIENTE
249 VALENCIA    VALENCIA    PICAYO
250 VALENCIA    VALENCIA    UTIEL
```

and I want this output:

```
{
    "ANDALUCIA":{
        "ALMERIA":[
            "ALMERIA",
            "EJIDO, EL",
            ...

        ],
        "CADIZ":[
            "JEREZ DE LA FRONTERA",
            ...
        ]
    },
    "ARAGON":{
        "HUESCA":[
            "ARGUIS",
            ...
        ],
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

What is the best way to achieve this though pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) for lists and then create nested dictionary:

```
s = df.groupby(['COMUNIDAD','PROVINCIA'])['EMPLAZAMIENTO'].agg(list)

d = {level: s.xs(level).to_dict() for level in s.index.levels[0]}
print (d)
{'ANDALUCIA': {'ALMERIA': ['ALMERIA', 'EJIDO, EL', 
                           'HUERCAL OVERA', 'PECHINA', 'VELEZ BLANCO']}, 
 'VALENCIA': {'VALENCIA': ['COFRENTES', 'MONDUBER',
                           'ONTENIENTE', 'PICAYO', 'UTIEL']}}
```

Last for json use:

```
import json
j = json.dumps(d)
print (j)
{"ANDALUCIA": {"ALMERIA": ["ALMERIA", "EJIDO, EL",
                           "HUERCAL OVERA", "PECHINA", "VELEZ BLANCO"]}, 
 "VALENCIA": {"VALENCIA": ["COFRENTES", "MONDUBER", 
                           "ONTENIENTE", "PICAYO", "UTIEL"]}}
```

Comment: perfect, just what i needed